# Mapnik usage in client server app

Tags: mapnik

I am trying to use mapnik in my project, but I think I might be using it inefficiently or just wrong.
Project is mapserver, one of requests from client is: get PNG of map providing current coordinates and radius. When I start the server I read s57 files, get them to PG db, using ogr2ogr, then I initialize mapnik like this:

```
  std::string mapnikDir =
      "/usr/lib/mapnik/2.2/input";  // mapnik-config --input-plugins
  mapnik::datasource_cache::instance().register_datasources(mapnikDir);
  whole_map_ = mapnik::Map(CANVAS_HEIGHT, CANVAS_WIDTH);
  mapnik::load_map(whole_map_, xml_file);
```

where `CANVAS_HEIGHT, CANVAS_WIDTH` are constants that store 1024 value, `xml_file` is file with mapnik styleguide, based on my db and layers I want to see and `whole_map_` is private field in the class of type `mapnik::Map`.

After that I am ready to process such queries.
Client sends me coordinates and radius, then I prepare the box which I want to render, I can do so using formulas to calculate [destination point given distance and bearing from start point](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), then I use this box like this:

```
  whole_map_.zoom_to_box(box);
  mapnik::image_32 im(CANVAS_HEIGHT, CANVAS_WIDTH);
  mapnik::agg_renderer<mapnik::image_32> ren(whole_map_, im);
  ren.apply();
  
  mapnik::save_to_file(im, output_file);
```

After that I send bytes of PNG file where I need.

So I have several questions, generally is this usage fair, or I am doing something not right, mapnik documentation is far from ideal and I am not sure if I understand what zoom_to_box really does. I am doing it quite often with different coordinates and radius as inputs.

Should I use bigger constants when I initialize the whole_map_ instance, do they even matter, because when I render constants tell the size of output picture.

If I want to use tiling, because some pictures take some time to render, and I want to break picture in parts, how to implement it? The guides I found don't seem to be useful, but I can be wrong.

I am doing project in c++.

Edit: Another question about map that I have. If I want a PNG at coordinates of green dot, and I know, that there are multiple map files that cover that area, is there a way to optimize fetching data or rendering, because in such regions it takes significantly more time to render picture than on "easy" ones
[image: overlapping area of map from QGis]

Comment: Answering last question, at https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/OptimizeRenderingWithPostGIS it says that mapnik gets data only from area that I am rendering, so the performance issue is caused by something else.